# Shortening a nested variable name

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code below `Node_T` is a `std::shared_ptr`, `element_type` will be `Node< T,U >`, and this type has member called `root_`;

Is there a way to shorten somehow this: `Node_T::element_type::root_` to just `root_`?

```
template<class Node_T>
const Node_T& root(Node_T& node)
    {
        Node_T::element_type::root_ = node;
        while (Node_T::element_type::root_->parent_)
        {

            Node_T::element_type::root_ = Node_T::element_type::root_->parent_;

        }

        return Node_T::element_type::root_;
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a few `typename`s in here?

Comment: @DeadMG well, root_ isn't a type name and I believe typename is suppose to indicate that what to the right of :: is a type, so I'm not sure if element_type requires typename in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++0x; then the first line of function `root(Node_T&)` can be,

```
auto &root_ = Node_T::element_type::root_;
// use root_ now onwards
```

Comment: It's not much longer to write `Node_T& root_ = Node_T::element_type::root_;` :)

Comment: @n.m. that's true, But if I am using C++0x, I would prefer `auto` (or `decltype`). Consider, that if `Node_T` is not `shared_ptr` and some `class D`; which is a derivation of some other `class B`. Making it `Node_T` ( = `B`) will silently discard its real type, however `auto` will still secure the `D&` type. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
Node_T::element_type::root_ = node;
```

From the above code, it seems that the type of `Node_T::element_type::root_` is just `Node_T`, because the type of `node` is `Node_T`. If so, then why don't you simply write:

```
Node_T tmp = node;
while (tmp->parent_)
{
    tmp = tmp->parent_;
}
Node_T::element_type::root_  = tmp;
return Node_T::element_type::root_;
```

Comment: You are making 2 copies of `node` here (we don't know the size of `Node_T`) and returning local variable `tmp` by `const` reference; which can be UB.

Comment: @iammilind: Its clear from the code that `node` is actually a pointer, so `Node_T tmp = node` wouldn't create any copy of the content. In fact, in your code `auto & root` is not needed, as `auto root` suffices.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's actually a `shared_ptr<>`; however, I am not sure if we can return a local copy by by reference. In my answer, I wanted to avoid extra copy of it, so I used reference.

Comment: @iammilind is right. Whey I've tried to do it yesterday as Nawaz suggesting I's given and warning about returning local copy.

Comment: @smallB: Then `return Node_T::element_type::root_` as I did now.

Answer (score 0):

How about a pointer?

```
template<class Node_T>
const Node_T& root(Node_T& node)
    {
        const Node_T * root_ = &node;
        while (root_->parent_)
        {
            root_ = root_->parent_;
        }
        return Node_T::element_type::root_ = *root_;
    }
```

This overwrites `Node_T::element_type::root_` only once, too.